# KVL in a BJT circuit

Tags: bjt, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how KVL is applied in a BJT circuit. Here's an example circuit diagram:

[image]

Assume I want to get Vc, so I think to myself that I must add up all the voltages on the right side of the loop to equal to 0. So I come up with this:

10 + Vc + Vce + Ve = 0

Vce is the voltage drop from collector to emitter, so I can substitute it like so

10 + Vc + Vc - Ve + Ve = 0

Which reduces down to 10 + 2 * Vc = 0

So Vc is just half the voltage of the battery (10v)? This didn't make any sense to me

After checking the solution manual, indeed KVL is applied but the equation is something completely different than what I had anticipated

Vc = 10 - IcRc

Where did this equation come from? And isn't Vc = IcRc according to Ohm's law? So we're subtracting the battery voltage from the Vc to get Vc?

The original problem can be found [here](http://whites.sdsmt.edu/classes/ee320/notes/320Lecture12.pdf) (Problem #1)

Comment: Draw in the actual sources, and define a reference direction for each branch. Now watch your signs when you write your equations.

Comment: For example, I'd end up with something like \$10 - I_c(R_c) - V_{ce} + I_e(R_e) = 0\$ (with \$I_e\$ being the current *in* to the emitter)

Comment: KVL applies to loops. You should convert this into a loop by drawing an actual voltage source instead of just labeling it 10V. Then you will see that you have accidentally reversed the polarity. The starting equation is Ic*Rc + Vce + Ie*Re = 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've overcomplicated your analysis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBWwDP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*

The collector voltage is just the supply voltage minus the voltage drop across Rc.

$$V_C = 10 V - V_{RC}$$

The voltage drop across Rc is given by Ohm's Law (as you stated) using the collector current.

$$ V_{RC} = I_C \cdot R_C$$

and substituting this gives you

$$V_C = 10 V - I_C \cdot R_C$$

---

Since the base is held at 4 V the emmitter will be held at about 3.3 V and this will determine the current through Re. The current through Rc will be the current through Re less the base current.

Comment: Ohhhh having the diagram drawn like that makes a lot more sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing \$V_c\$ (voltage at the collector) with the voltage drop accross \$R_c\$. You really have \$V_{R_c}\ = 10 - V_c\$ or \$V_c = 10 - V_{R_c} = 10 - I_cR_c\$

Comment: Yes! I realized the confusion after looking at the below diagram! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Using KVL**

10 - Voltage drop across Rc - Voltage drop across the junction - Voltage drop across Re = 0

$$10 - I_cR_c - V_{ce} - I_eR_e = 0$$

Remembering that:
$$ V_{ce} = V_c - V_e$$ and
$$ V_e = I_eR_e$$

We get:
$$ 10 - I_cR_c - V_c + V_e - V_e = 0$$
$$ 10 - I_cR_c = V_c$$

Vc is not IcRc. Vc is the voltage at the collector with respect to GND, while IcRc is the voltage drop across Rc as a result of Ic.